# How to correctly refresh auth token in the background google-apis using flutter

Tags: flutter, google-api, google-calendar-api

Right now I use the method `clientViaUserConsent`, to authenticate my user and thus be able to use the **Google API**, in this case, **calendar api**, the problem is that the way it is built now requests this permission every time the user enters the app, this it is a problem since it is annoying for the user,

***Is there a way to do this automatically by refreshing the authentication token in the background every time the user enters the app?***

I understand the idea of ​​storing the token and the refresh token but I don't know how to implement it

here is my code:

```dart
var _clientID = new ClientId(Secret.getId(), "");
    const _scopes = const [cal.CalendarApi.calendarScope];
    await clientViaUserConsent(_clientID, _scopes, Prompt.prompt).then((AuthClient client) async {
      CalendarClient.calendar = cal.CalendarApi(client);
      print(client);
    });
```

Comment: Hi, what kind of application do you have, web application or installed/console application? Also, can you provide a minimal reproducible example?

Comment: I have the same exact problem. I am currently thinking only of Android. Independently I tried the idea suggested by @Zach, but the Google Api fails when tries to refresh the token: the `client_secret` is missing when the `ClientId` instance is created and it is not provided along with the `client_id` by the Google Platform.
Probably the best approach is to implement Google SignIn...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the credentials are stored in the client variable.

```
AccessToken: client.credentials.accessToken.data
RefreshToken: client.credentials.refreshToken
Expiration: client.credentials.accessToken.expiry
IDToken: client.credentials.idToken
```

You can then store these and build a new request later when they sign in as such:

```
void getEventsPastAuth() async {
  var client = Client();
  AccessCredentials credentials = await _calendarCredentials.getCredetial();
  AccessCredentials refreshedCred =
      await refreshCredentials(_credentialsID, credentials, client);

  client = autoRefreshingClient(_credentialsID, credentials, client);
  var calendar = CalendarApi(client);
  var now = DateTime.now();
  var calEvents = calendar.events.list('primary',
      maxResults: 100,
      timeMin: now,
      timeMax: DateTime(now.year, now.month + 1, now.day));
  calEvents.then((Events events) {
    events.items!.forEach((Event event) {
      debugPrint(event.summary);
    });
  });
}
```

The variable credentials is the stored variables as an AccessCredential

```
AccessCredentials(
      AccessToken("Bearer", accessToken, DateTime.parse(expiration)),
      refreshToken,
      _scopes,
      idToken: idToken);
```

If you figure out how to have access to multiple user's calendars simultaneously, let me know. I'm currently struggling on figuring out how I can search multiple users' calendars after user consent in Flutter.

Answer (score 0):

**Add following dependencies**

```
  google_sign_in: ^4.4.6
  googleapis_auth: ^0.2.11+1
  googleapis: ^0.54.0
```

**Follow the Methods**

*Initialize google SignIn clientId and scope*

```
  final GoogleSignIn _googleSignIn = GoogleSignIn(
  clientId:
      'hghdf4876487984398',
  scopes: <String>[
    googleAPI.CalendarApi.CalendarScope,
  ]);
```

*Call this method for when ever you want*

```
    void initState() {
    getGoogleData();
    super.initState();
  }
```

*Here the funtion*

```
    Future getGoogleData() async {
    final GoogleSignInAccount googleUser = await _googleSignIn.signIn();
    final _accessToken= await googleUser.authentication;

    print(_accessToken.accessToken);
    try {
      final GoogleAPIClient httpClient =
          GoogleAPIClient(await googleUser.authHeaders);
      final googleAPI.CalendarApi calendarAPI =
          googleAPI.CalendarApi(httpClient);
    } catch (e) {
      refreshFn(googleUser);
//this funtion used for refresh token
    }
  }
```

*Refresh Funtion*

```
  refreshFn(googleUser) {
    googleUser.clearAuthCache();
    getGoogleEventsData().whenComplete(() => Navigator.pop(context));
  }
```